# IntelliJ scala plugin Invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

**I am trying to install Scala Plugin to IntelliJ IDE. I have tried both ways available, one is from Marketplace, and another is from local disk.Getting error** `Invalid END header (bad central directory offset)`

**Step followed: **

[image]

**Error: **

[image]

**Important Note:**

1. I am using Java version 18.0.2 and IntelliJ version 2022.2.3.
2. I am using machine which having organisational firewall.
3. Even unable to update existing plugin Kotlin from update option, same error getting occured.

*#Scala #Intellij #Intellijplugin*

Expecting to install scala plugin.

Comment: Seems you are trying to install Scala plugin that is not compatible (it has 2022.3 version but your IDE is 2022.2). Try downloading different version of the plugin: https://i.imgur.com/rtBBMzB.png

Comment: No Help. Updating screenshots with the version suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the Netskope client is running in your VM/VDI, if it is running you'd need to disable it and then try to install the plugins the usual way. It would let you install the plugins. In my case, it was the netskope client that was causing this issue inside my VDI. Once disabled, I was able to install the plugins. Please see if another Netskope alternate application is running in your system.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are getting above error in your virtual machine than please follow below steps this worked for me:**

1. Download the compatible scala plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala/versions in your local machine system
   [image]
2. Upload the zip file to your one drive from local machine system
3. To go your virtual machine and download this zip file from your one drive
4. Use import plugin from disk option in intelliJ IDE and use the downloaded zip file.
   [image]

Comment: Please read my problem Line no 1 "and another is from local disk". Not working. Same issue.

Comment: I mean if you are getting error on your local system, not on virtual machine, then download the compatible scala zip file from another system and upload it to your one drive or send it as attachment by mail. After this goto your current system and download the zip from your one drive or from mail, then Use import plugin from disk option in intellij and use the downloaded zip file.

Comment: It's not about the downloading plugin. I have it on my machine and have internet access also to get it done from the link. 
Error is after import. I hope you are able to see my screenshots provided.

Comment: I also faced the same issue and found that issue was with downloading plugins through internet. During downloading scala plugins zip file looks good  but when going for import in intellij then error had shown. So what I observed that scala plugin is going to corrupted during downloading due to organisational firewall.

Comment: The plugin not getting corrupt.